# Background image not showing up in css while using header tag

Tags: html, css, styles

I am implementing a html, css code and my backround image is not showing up. here is my header specs.

```
.header
{
  height:200px;
  background-color: green;
  border-bottom: 2px solid ;
  background-image: url(https://ibb.co/3W6XD3Z);
}
```

Where am I getting wrong?

EDIT: Added more code snippet

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Users\ratho\OneDrive\Desktop\html project\test1.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="header">
      <p class="head">SHE MATTERS</p>
      <div class="header-list">
      <ul >
        <li><a href="#" class="header-link">Join Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="header-link">Login</a></li>
      </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
      <div class="main">
        </div>
      <footer>
      </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you need to provide more information a code snippet would be good

Comment: I added the html part of the code. Please review it again.

Comment: Are you sure the URL returns an image??

Comment: Try With different image scr

Answer (score 1):

Below is your answer

```css
.header {
         background-image:url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593460354583-4224ab273cfe?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=966&q=80')
        }
```

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <title>
       Test
      </title>
  </head>
  <body class='header'>
  <h1>My Page</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to set the CSS property `background-image` to a webpage... using the Embed Codes section of the image host, you can get the image src... your css should be:

```css
.header {
   height:200px;
   background-color: green;
   border-bottom: 2px solid ;
   background-image:url('https://i.ibb.co/rM8PCjr/Whats-App-Image-2021-04-21-at-09-58-28.jpg');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem was your background image address this will do :

```css
.header
    {
      height:200px;
      background-color: green;
      border-bottom: 2px solid ;
      background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/0Z4Ng7b/Whats-App-Image-2021-04-21-at-09-58-28.jpg);
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Users\ratho\OneDrive\Desktop\html project\test1.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="header">
      <p class="head">SHE MATTERS</p>
      <div class="header-list">
      <ul >
        <li><a href="#" class="header-link">Join Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="header-link">Login</a></li>
      </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
      <div class="main">
        </div>
      <footer>
      </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is your answer
problem was with the background image url

```
  .header
  {
  height:200px;
  background-color: green;
  border-bottom: 2px solid ;
  background-image: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/04/15/13/11/bridge 
  6181079_960_720.jpg ); 
  }
```

W3 Schools [you can learn more](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp)